# what's the difference between 'onClick' and 'onMouseEnter' in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add side toggle menu box in main page which is positioning on right side of document when the button is clicked.

I made a function for toggling action(you can check the function below) with some of react hooks and added by using `onClick()` method. I clicked the btn to check if it works, but it doesn't. I changed `onClick()` method to `onMouseEnter()` and it worked. I added callback(`onClick(()=>{function()})`) but it still doesn't work.

I think toggling function doesn't have any problem(because it worked properly when it's on `onMouseEnter`). Some mechanisms of them makes the difference. I checked the docs of javascript but it was not helpful.

I wish somebody provide me a demonstration of this.

Here is my codes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../css/side-toggle.css";
import hbgBtn from "../image/hamburgerBtn.png";

const SideBar = ({ wid = 380, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
    console.log('1')
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container" wid={wid}>
      <img onMouseEnter={(e) => toggleMenu(e)} 
        className={!isOpen ? "show-btn" : "hide"}
        src={hbgBtn}
        alt=""
      />
      <div onMouseEnter={closeMenu} className={isOpen? "dimmer" : 'hide'}>{children}</div>
      <div className={isOpen ? "side-column" : "hide"}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

(and i will appreciate when you understand my wierd English. I'm ESL)

Comment: Can you provide a working demo codesandbox link?

Comment: Basicaly the mouse enter fires a function when your mouse hovers over the element. The on click is fired whenever you click to the element.

Comment: The difference is exactly the same as that of native JS. You can just search online. It should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possiblity that you may have made some error while styling. I have tried my best to replicate your code and it works for me fine.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const SideBar = ({ wid = 380, children }) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
    console.log('1');
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen((isOpen) => !isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div onClick={(e) => toggleMenu(e)}>
        <img
          className={!isOpen ? 'show-btn' : 'hide'}
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/1024px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div onMouseEnter={closeMenu} className={isOpen ? 'dimmer' : 'hide'}>
        {children}
      </div>
      <div className={isOpen ? 'side-column' : 'hide'}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

Here is the stackblitz code link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xtwxzc?file=src/App.js

Comment: sorry for late appreciation. i tried and succeeded! Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you accept this as solution if this worked for you